# Odoo 13 : How to check all companies in allowed companies after logging?

Tags: python, odoo

I set up an environment with multi-company in Odoo 13.

I allowed these companies to the user Mitchell Admin :
**YourCompany**, **YourCompanyBis**, **AnotherCompany**.

When I log in, YourCompany is the default one and the box is checked.
I checked the three companies, then logged out. 
After I logged in, the three companies is still checked, seems to be fine.

**Problem:**
After 2 days or more, I relogged in, all companies are unchecked except **`YourCompany`** and that is my problem.

So how can I checked all companies when I log in?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a module called "Un/Select all companies" available in Odoo Apps to resolve this problem, you can check the app [here](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/select_all_companies/).

This app provide features that allow you to check all the companies in dropdown menu in one click and unsellect all (except one) in one click also.

Note that you have to manually click the button (on dropdown) to select/unselect the companies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this base on community odoo source. If you go to `Setting > Users & Companies > Users > select your user` (Mitchell Admin - in this case). In `Access Rights` tab you will see Multi Companies section, there are 2 options there:

- Allowed Companies: All company you will see up there,
- Default Company: Default select company.

These are 2 relationship fields. Customizing this will take some serious time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:  web/static/src/xml/base.xml
and comment last line see below

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
<t t-foreach="widget.user_companies" t-as="company">
<div class="dropdown-item d-flex py-0 px-0" data-menu="company" t-att-data-company-id="company[0]">
<t t-set="is_allowed" t-value="widget.allowed_company_ids.includes(company[0])"/>
<t t-set="is_current" t-value="company[0] === widget.current_company"/>
<div role="menuitemcheckbox" t-att-aria-checked="true" t-att-aria-label="company[1]" tabindex="0" class="ml-auto pl-3 pr-3 border border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 toggle_company o_py">
<span style="height: 2rem;">
<t t-if="is_allowed">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square pt-2"></i>
</t>
        <t t-if="!is_allowed">
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square pt-2"></i>
         <!--<i class="fa fa-fw fa-square-o pt-2"></i>-->
        </t>
```